# Referencing indirect cells in excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

So I am trying to have a cell reference in my code be an indirect reference. For instance I want to update the value in column B cell "X" where X is defined in cell B1. 
Here is the code that I am currently trying but I keep getting an out of range exception. I am very new to VBA so my syntax could just be very far off.

```
Workbooks("Personal_Finances").Sheets(categoryType).Range("$B($B$1)").Value = ammount
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
with Workbooks("Personal_Finances").Sheets(categoryType)
    .cells(.Range("B1").Value, "B") = ammount
    'alternate
    .Range("B" & .Range("B1").Value) = ammount
end with
```

Here .Range("B1").Value is used for the row reference in .Cells. The alternate is closer to what you were originally attempting.

I've wrapped the working code in a With ... End With block to maintain the parent worksheet reference.

There is no need for **$** in a quoted string cell reference unless used in a formula populating multiple cells at once.

Answer (score 0):

def a new variable and assign the value of cell $b$1 to it.

```
dim temp_row as integer
temp_row.value =Workbooks("Personal_Finances").Sheets("categoryType").Range("B1").Value
Workbooks("Personal_Finances").Sheets(categoryType).Range("$B" & temp_row).Value = amount
```

or just do the same thing in one line.

Answer (score -1):

Or:

```
With Workbooks("Personal_Finances").Sheets(categoryType).Range("B1")
    .Offset(.Value2 - 1) = ammount
End With
```

Where the “With ... End With” block references cell B1 of wanted worksheet in wanted workbook and the nested statement offsets it by its value minus one (to reach wanted row)

Comment: I'd appreciate the brave and masked downvoter to say what's wrong with my answer and contribute enhancing my answer. but I'm afraid he is not that brave and will stay masked